# Acquire fuse_file_info in FUSE's truncate()

Tags: fuse

Is it possible to acquire the [`struct fuse_file_info* fi`](https://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/structfuse__file__info.html) in the function `truncate()`? Why is it not there in the first place?

```
int truncate(const char* path, off_t size)
```

I'm storing my file descriptor in the file handler, `fh`, of the `fuse_file_info` structure. The function `open()` appears to be called beforehand so that structure is created for the file. The description of `fh` is: "*File handle. May be filled in by filesystem in open(). Available in all other file operations*".

(As a last resort I'm thinking of having a structure to store this information, saved into a hash map, and then use the file handler to store the key. This would allow me to search the structure, using the `path`, in order to find the respective file descriptor.)

Note: I'm actually using `jnr-fuse` but since it mimics `libfuse` I'm not asking specifically for it; what works for one should (sort of) work for the other.

Comment: [Additional truncate-related info](https://sourceforge.net/p/fuse/mailman/message/7409252/) found on the FUSE mailing list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it not there in the first place?

Because of implementation of `truncate` in the Linux kernel. You can see signature [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/truncate).